# Nagios status information

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino, nagios

I am working on a project that has my computer communicating with an arduino board that reads the sensor output and test it in a C plugin ( [Reading from a serial port after writing on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675127/reading-from-a-serial-port-after-writing-on-it/17720837#17720837)) for nagios. My problem is that the status information is always null. My plugin is in the lib"/usr/local/nagios/libexec"
In commands.cfg I added the following:

```
define command{
    command_name    arduino_temp_sensor
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/essai.c
    }
```

And in the localhost.cfg I added the following:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service         
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Temp
        check_command                   arduino_temp_sensor
        }
```

I'm confused if the output of the printf should appear in the status information or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends withers your  `/libexec` output in standard format or not. check the `/var/` file

Comment: I checked  /usr/local/nagios/var/status.dat and in my own plugin I have: plugin_output=(null)

Comment: Then it can't give information.

Comment: How can I check if the /libexec output is standard or not?

Comment: [Nagios plug-in development guidelines](http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I removed .c as following:

```
define command{
     command_name    arduino_temp_sensor
     command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/essai
     }
```