# RS-232 communication with RPi

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, hardware, raspberry-pi

This is a follow up question to this original post:

[RaspberryPi RS-232 trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072518/raspberrypi-rs-232-trouble)

I made changes to my code per the accepted answer, the terminal is now set up for blocking and canonical input. The `read()` now works as expected, with the exception of the very first read(which is typically some extra random symbols mixed with some good data) I get single lines of data from the laser range finder representing exactly what I expect to see.

However, I now have an issue that if I do too many reads, the laser range finder is put into a non-operating state, stops communication, and can only be reset by doing a power cycle. This has happened with as few as 4 reads on the device, and I haven't been able to do more than 8 reads. It doesn't matter if the reads are all at once, or spanned across several program starts.

```
int main(){
    int uart0_filestream = -1;
    int loop, i, sentBytes;
    int isError, rx_length;
    unsigned char rx_buffer[256];

    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    fcntl(uart0_filestream, F_SETFL, 0);

    if(uart0_filestream == -1){
        printf("ERROR: Unable to open UART\n");
        checkError(errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct termios options;

    isError = tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);

    if(isError < 0){
        printf("ERROR: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        checkError(errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //set c ontrol options and baud
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);

    //set 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    //set input options
    options.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);        //strip parity
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); //turn off software flow control

    //set canonical input processing
    options.c_lflag |= (ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE);

    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    isError = tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);

    if(isError < 0){
        printf("ERROR: tcsetattr failed.\n");
        checkError(errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //read() successfully returns expected data, with the exception of the first 
    //read. Reading more than 6-8 times, regardless of same session or restarting
    //program puts LRF in non-working state which requires a power cycle to fix
    for(i=0; i<4;i++ ){
        rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);

        if(rx_length < 0){
            printf("ERROR: read() failed.\n");
            checkError(errno);
        }

        if(rx_length > 0){
            printf("rx_lentgh = %i:\t ", rx_length);
            for(loop=0; loop<rx_length; loop++){
                printf("%c", rx_buffer[loop]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    //writing once has no affect, sending command has no affect
    //looping the write, eventually 'something' gets to the LRF
    //but it puts it in the same state as when reading too many
    //times and have to power cycle
    for(i = 0; i<8; i++){
        sentBytes = write(uart0_filestream, "o\n", 2);

        if(sentBytes < 2){
            printf("ERROR: write() failed.\n");
            checkError(errno);
        }   
    }

    close(uart0_filestream);
}
```

I don't believe it is the range finder, as I can run minicom and it will continuously display the output successfully.

As noted in the comments of my code, I also have trouble writing any commands to the laser range finder. Each command consists of a single character, followed by a new line. One write has no affect, but looping several times can put the device in the same state as reading too many times.

I have read [Posix Serial Programming Guide](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html), and tried different combinations of flags that I believe might affect either the reading or writing, but have had no success.

Comment: Put some checks to get the error status of `uart0_filestream` before doing the `read()`.  See if an error condition pre-dates the hang.

Comment: How is the communication with this laser range finder supposed to work?  Most devices work on a simple command/response basis: the host (the master) sends a command, and the device (the slave) responds with a reply message.  The slave device only responds to a command; it never sends anything spontaneously or unsolicited.  Your program expects to read 4 lines, and then sends a command 8 times.  Can you simulate that with `minicom`?

Comment: When in a measuring mode, the range finder sends data at a rate of 10 Hz or 200 Hz, depending on the mode it is in. It sends the data constantly, no command is required to get the data. The code I have so far is just for testing. I just want to prove I can read the data as much as I want, and can successfully send commands.

Minicom doesn't have the ability for me to explicitly do a read() 4 times. It just continuously reads what is coming in. Sending data just interrupts the process of reading the data.

Comment: What is the purpose of sending the same command eight times? (1) Simulate the 8 `write()`s in `minicom` by creating a plain text file of 16 bytes equivalent to "o<NL>o<NL>o<NL>..." and then use 'send ASCII file' to transfer the text just like your program.  Or (2) stop sending the command 8 times.  Send it just once.

Comment: Sending the command 8 times is a test. There is no purpose other than that. When I send it once, nothing happens. So I looped it to see if sending it more than once did anything. Which it does. So far, I have had 0 successful attempts at sending the range finder a command. Ideally, of course, I only need to send the command once. In minicom, I only need to send a command once.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] This lead suggestion is my embarrassment - thought the string was "o/n".

The amount of data sent is short by 1.

```
// sentBytes = write(uart0_filestream, "o\n", 2);
// if(sentBytes < 2){
sentBytes = write(uart0_filestream, "o\n", 3);
if(sentBytes < 3){
```

---

Minor: Unclear why read buffer is reduced by 1 (sizeof rx_buffer is 256).  `read()` is not going to append a `\0` and neither does this code.  Code nicely treats the incoming data as an array of bytes.  Although in `printf("%c"...` something could be done if !isgraph(rx_buffer[loop])`.

```
// rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255)
rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, sizeof rx_buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I believed the newline character to be a single byte. I will try changing that and seeing if that helps.

Comment: @jrpharis  Face palm on my part.