# Why characters received in serial connection only after pressing enter?

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart

I have a simple PC to board connection using serial (9600, no parity, 8 bits, no hw flow)
I opened simple terminal *with teraterm) in PC and enter keys in teraterm and in board, I just do

```
 cat /dev/ttyO5
```

I see the pressed characters in scope, but I see the characters in the board console, only after pressing "enter" in teraterm (as if they are stored in some FIFO in Linux driver which only enter triggers out)

1. why are the characters received in Linux driver only when pressing enter key  ?
2. Is there some way to receive the characters without pressing the enter key ? (we use some protocol of ascii so it does not make sense to send this as dummy)

Thanks for advise,
Ran

Comment: Is the device really `tty05`, or should it be `ttyO5`?

Comment: right about the tty05, I've fixed the typo in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I see the characters in the board console, only after pressing "enter" in teraterm

The behavior you describe is characteristic of canonical read (aka reading lines).
The behavior you seem to want is called non-canonical read (aka raw read or binary read).

> 1. why are the characters received in Linux driver only when pressing enter key ?

No, the Linux serial port driver is receiving every character as it is appears on the wire.
Each character is buffered (typically in DMA-able memory), and then forwarded to a *line discipline handler*, which is also buffering the received data.
A canonical **read()** syscall by the userland program is blocked until the line discipline handler detects a line termination character.

> 2. Is there some way to receive the characters without pressing the enter key ?

Yes, before issuing the `cat` command, configure the serial port to non-canonical mode:

```
stty -F /dev/tty05 raw
```

or more likely the correct device node is

```
stty -F /dev/ttyO5 raw
```

Or use the *termios* interface to configure the serial port to non-canonical mode in a userspace program on the board.  Sample code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437593/how-to-read-a-binary-data-over-serial-terminal-in-c-program/12457195#12457195).

Documentation on how to properly program a serial port are
[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html) and [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html).