# New line character significance in serial port communication

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, rs485

We are testing serial port communication. There are two tty nodes /dev/ttyUSB8 and /dev/ttyUSB9 on the device.

When I transmit buffer from /dev/ttyUSB8 to /dev/ttyUSB9 I don't receive data on the /dev/ttyUSB9 read call if the buffer doesn't contain new line.

Transmit Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void write_func()
{
    int fdw;
    int i;
    fdw = open("/dev/ttyUSB8", O_RDWR);
    printf("fdw : %d\n",fdw);

    printf("%ld\n", write(fdw, "Hello", 6));
    close(fdw);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    write_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Receive Code

```
void read_thread()
{

    int fdr;
    char buf[] = "NoData";

    fdr = open("/dev/ttyUSB9", O_RDWR);
    printf("fdr : %d\n",fdr);

    printf("%s: %ld\n", __func__, read(fdr, buf, 6));

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    close(fdr);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    read_thread();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't receive data with the above call, but when I add '\n in the write call i get data in the read block call.

```
 printf("%ld\n", write(fdw, "Hello\n", 7));
```

What is the significance of new line character in this..

Update:

I added the code to reset canonical mode, still it didn't work:

```
void write_thread()
{

    int fdw;
    int i;
    struct termios config;
    fdw = open("/dev/ttymib24", O_RDWR);
    printf("fdw : %d\n",fdw);
    tcgetattr(fdw, &config);
    config.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(fdw, TCSANOW, &config);    
    printf("%ld\n", write(fdw, "Hello", 6));
    close(fdw);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the tty is line buffered. Did you try to flush after writing?

Comment: To sort out this kind of problems it is important to verify whether the text is not written or not received. Did you verify with a terminal program if the data is sent or not?

Comment: Verified with cat And echo, it works

Comment: What works? What did you do exactly? Something like `cat xyz> /dev/tty` or something like `cat < /dev/tty`?

Comment: Cat /dev/ttyusb

Comment: What's the difference between above two cat commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183356/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-md-jamal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why characters received in serial connection only after pressing enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214759/why-characters-received-in-serial-connection-only-after-pressing-enter)

Answer (score 1):

Your tty is probably in canonical mode.

Try to reset ICANON by using `tcsetattr()`. Something like this:

```
struct termios termiosv;
tcgetattr(fd, &termiosv);
termiosv.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termiosv);
```

More information in man page of [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html):

> ```
>    In canonical mode:
>
>    * Input is made available line by line.  An input line is available
>      when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at
>      the start of line).  Except in the case of EOF, the line delimiter
>      is included in the buffer returned by read(2).
> ```

Comment: @md.jamal Did you read the snippet from the man page? **Input** is affected. You need to add it into the read thread.