# method to log stdin characters to any command line program (linux)?

Tags: logging, stdin

On linux is there a tool to see exactly which characters a certain program is reading from stdin?  Preferably logging them to a file with time stamps, but just logging them raw to a file will do.

This input is actually translated characters from an IR remote, and I need to see exactly which ones and how many are actually reaching the application.  In this case I'm working with somebody else's binary, and even if I did get a version of the source code and compiled it the issue is not actually in the target program, it is upstream.  So a more general solution would be preferred.  The intercepting tool can be run as root, if that is required.

Note that in this case the program whose input I want to monitor is normally started by yet another program.  So what I'm looking for is a tool that does something like:

```
   intercept -stdin -pid $PID_OF_RUNNING_PROGRAM -log file
```

Comment: Note strace doesn't quite do it here because it only emits the logged stdin characters on an EOL or when the program exits.  Ie, like this: " strace -ff -e trace=write -e write=1,2 -p 11856".  If there was a way to make it emit input character by character then that would do it.

Comment: Check out the strace command

Comment: `strace -tt -e trace=read -e read=0 -p #####` will show them as they're read.

Comment: "strace -tt -e trace=read -e read=0 -p ######" as suggested by Mark Plotnick is not working for me.  At the first character it emits a time stamp and "read(0," but then it waits for an EOL before emitting the characters.  In this application there is no EOL, ever.

Comment: strace will show when a read completes. If strace is not showing any output, it means the read hasn't completed and your program is still waiting in a read system call. If your program is reading in canonical mode, it'll wait for EOL or the buffer to be filled; no user-level tracing program can change that. Do you actually want to see the characters as they pass through the device driver, before they're read?

Comment: The program in question acts on each character as it is received. It is probably using getc() or some equivalent.

Comment: An alternative might be to put the serial device into "raw" mode, if the program can tolerate that. This can be done with a separate program. See [How to read a binary data over serial terminal in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437593/how-to-read-a-binary-data-over-serial-terminal-in-c-program/)

Comment: You are right, the device mode matters.  The strace command works as desired (character by character) when monitoring "nano test.txt" keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

tee command can log stdin and stdout in command line. this is not the correct format this question want, but write it here may help other people.

```
root@aliecs:~# echo -e "hello\nworld" | tee in.log | grep hello | tee out.log
hello
root@aliecs:~# cat in.log 
hello
world
root@aliecs:~# cat out.log 
hello
root@aliecs:~#
```