# Serial port reads are delayed (and bytes missing)

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, cdc, termios

I have a Rasperry Pi and a Raspberry Pi Pico communicating together via serial.
I was using the UART pins on both, and everything was fine in terms of communications, except some environments were noisy, so I switched to USB CDC (USB using a differential pair...)

On the Pico side, I've had to do some changes to my code, but it seems now OK, after adding this:

```
stdio_set_translate_crlf(&stdio_usb, false);
```

(My protocol is binary, so translation was interfereing)

Now on the "Regular Pi", things have gone a bit wrong. Using the UART, all reads were non-buffered/instantaneous.
Now that I'm over USB, it seems I have to wait for a fair bit of data to come before anything is transferred to my program. Note that other programs (like minicom) do not have this issue.
I also seem to miss a fair few bytes.

I made a special program to run on the Pico that continuously outputs bytes from 0x00 to 0xFF. If I connect the Pico to a Windows host, run Putty and log the session, I get all the bytes, no problem.

My own software on the Raspberry Pi misses a lot of bytes.

I also tried this command:

```
(stty raw; cat > received.log) < /dev/ttyACM0
```

Most of the times, bytes between 0x0A and 0x16 are missing (I presume 0x0A triggers something related to CR/LF, but I'm not sure why characters till 0x16 (not included) get skipped. 0x7E and 0x7F are missing fairly often too.
Occasionally, the full 256 bytes seems captures in a raw.
I added a 10ms sleep in my loop on the Pico Pi, and the command above captures data properly. (The original UART was meant to run at 9600-115200 bps, nothing higher, my loop currently outputs >200 kbps, so that's quite enough for my needs).

Here's the initialisation code:

```
uart0_fd = ::open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);       //Open in non blocking read/write mode

struct termios options;
tcgetattr(uart0_fd, &options);
cfmakeraw(&options);
options.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CSTOPB | CREAD;      //<Set baud rate
options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | IGNBRK;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = ICANON | NOFLSH;
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;
tcflush(uart0_fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(uart0_fd, TCSANOW, &options);

struct termios tty;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
if (tcgetattr (uart0_fd, &tty) != 0)
{
  printf ("error %d from tggetattr\r\n", errno);
  return;
}

tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

if (tcsetattr (uart0_fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) { ... }
```

And here's the reading code:

```
void printHex(const uint8_t *data, const size_t size)
{
  for (uint32_t index = 0; index < size; ++index)
  {
    printf("%.2X",data[index]);
  }
}

void execute()
{
  printf("UART thread started\r\n");

  sendOverUart(COMMAND_RESEND_ALL, 0xFFFF);

  int local_uart0_fd = uart0_fd;

  unsigned char buffer[100];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

  while (!shouldFinish)
  {
    int bytesRead = read(local_uart0_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    buffer[bytesRead + 1] = '\0';
    if (-1 == bytesRead)
    {
      if (errno != EAGAIN)
      {
        printf("UART... error reading %d\r\n", errno);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printHex(buffer, bytesRead);
      fflush(stdout);
      continue;
    }
    if (EFAULT == errno)
    {

    }
  }
  ::close(local_uart0_fd);
  printf("UART thread finished\r\n");
}
```

As I said, it was working fine with the UART pins (/dev/serial0 on my Pi), did I miss anything, do I need to make something different due to USB?
I need it to be "quick" (i.e. be able get the bytes without buffering) and reliable (i.e. not miss part of the bytes received).

The current output of my program on the Raspberry Pi is consistently 00-0A, then DE-FF, consistenly capturing 88 out of 256 byte [I suppose, I haven't time, maybe it captures 88 out of 512 or more...].

Comment: With Linux, your program accesses a serial terminal rather than a UART or USB CDC. Your initialization for that serial terminal is poorly written and not reliable. See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html) and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/serial/serial.pdf). This is not baremetal, so you cannot avoid "*buffering*". For an example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437593/how-to-read-a-binary-data-over-serial-terminal-in-c-program/12457195#12457195

Comment: Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680  You enable canonical mode, which explains why control characters are intercepted. Your termios reads of the serial terminal are *timed* reads, but your read syscalls are non-blocking! You are using non-blocking mode to poll system buffers, and that is not faster than blocking mode. BTW terminating binary data with a null byte makes no sense, and flawed when using a return code that has not been checked.

Comment: `cfmakeraw` should be all the configuration you need.  As @sawdust pointed out, you're then enabling canonical mode, but *all* the extra flags you're changing are either harmful or do nothing, so don't change them.  For example, baud rate is not used for USB communications.  The only reason it exists is for a CDC device which turns the data into actual UART signals at the other end.  You're receiving in software straight from the USB stack.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it working. Now I'm annoyed because it's thanks to both your comments. The "cfmakeraw" alone fixed the delay issue, and sawdust comment on blocking/non-blocking helped me solve the missing bytes. Given the extra details (sorry Ben Voigt, you're also giving details, but I knew them already) I'd ask sawdust if you could write an answer for me to accept.

Comment: @sawdust Also thanks for going the extra mile, I'm not even sure why I had the extra \0, it's not used, there are a lot of \0 in my binary protocol. I think I had it for when I enable debug mode, the Pico then sends human readable data, and I can just print it, the extra \0 makes sure it won't go beyond boundaries regardless of what the Pico sends. I'd also say, even in baremetal there's some buffering (like a 16 bytes FIFO), interrupts can be masked, you don't know how long it'll take to read data. I meant something like "I want to get the data less than 100ms after it arrived".

Comment: @sawdust Why do you say my calls are non-blocking despite the 0.5s blocking? Anyway, you talking about me polling the system buffer made me change tty.c_cc[VMIN] to 100 and I don't miss bytes anymore. My goal was to actually read in blocking mode, this happens in its own thread, I just want a reasonnable enough timeout that the thread can read every now and then the flag that signals it should end. I don't get why the previous code wouldn't work, I'd exepct it to poll every so often, and when there's data in the buffer, get all of it. System buffer is too small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I said, it was working fine with the UART pins (/dev/serial0 on my Pi), did I miss anything, do I need to make something different due to USB?

With Linux, your program accesses a serial terminal rather than a UART or USB CDC. Your initialization for that serial terminal is poorly written and not reliable. See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.ing.iac.es/%7Edocs/external/serial/serial.pdf).

I'm skeptical that the code you posted actually passed binary data with the UART. After the **cfmakeraw()** call to configure non-canonical mode, your code proceeds with superfluous, hard termios assignments, including the disastrous

```c
options.c_lflag = ICANON | NOFLSH;
```

that puts the serial terminal in canonical mode. This is the simple explanation for why ASCII control characters are not appearing in your read buffer.

For an example of proper use of **cfmakeraw()**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437593/how-to-read-a-binary-data-over-serial-terminal-in-c-program/12457195#12457195).

---

Even though you specify a timed read with

```c
tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout
```

this termios specification is overridden by the non-blocking mode of the `uart0_fd` file descriptor. That mode was (redundantly) specified when the serial terminal was opened (and commented):

```c
uart0_fd = ::open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);       //Open in non blocking read/write mode
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680) for more details. Note the mention of the EAGAIN errno, which is dealt with properly in your code.

If you're skeptical about this precedence, then simply try VMIN=0 and VTIME=250 for a timed read of 25 seconds. The actual duration of the **read()** syscall should be rather obvious, and indicate whether the termios or file-descriptor mode has precedence.

---

> I meant something like "I want to get the data less than 100ms after it arrived".

Latency when reading a serial terminal can be problematic. There was a good discussion on a now-deleted forum where a developer tweaked his Linux SBC down to just a few milliseconds latency. The time was measured with an oscilloscope capturing the data on the wire and a GPIO flipping when the **read()** completes. The key tweaks IIRC were using the ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY flag with the TIOC[GS]SERIAL ioctl, and increasing the priority of the serial driver's tasklet or workqueue.

> ... when there's data in the buffer, get all of it. System buffer is too small?

The termios buffer is typically 4K bytes.
With non-canonical termios reads, you have to compromise between efficient reads (i.e. fetch as many bytes as possible per syscall) and low latency. You can get **read()** to return (with some data) in less than 0.1 seconds by specifying VMIN=1 and VTIME>0.